# Angular project - backend return where object is empty

Tags: html, json, angular

I have Angular as a front end and a nested object like:

```
{
  "id": 3,
  "name": "Mary",
  "sex": "FEMALE",
  "currentPlane": {
     "airline": "american airlines"  
     },
}
```

Where current plane is empty should the backed return `currentPlane: {}` or is it better to drop `currentPlane` all together and return:

```
{
  "id": 3,
  "name": "Mary",
  "sex": "FEMALE",
}
```

I am new to Angular, but I think that it is better for the object to be present with empty braces {} as then it will meet object structure angular expects.

Is there a usual way for JSON to be sent to the angular view  where the object is empty.

For example will angular handle objects that are not present as long as they have the '?'

I hope this question is not too opinionated for SO.

Comment: Don't ask for opinions, and it won't be too opinionated. As it stands, you are only asking for opinions ("should the backed [sic] return ... or is it better"). Define "better" in objective terms and ask for references to back up opinions. Right now I could answer with "I don't like having empty object properties" and that would meet the terms of your question.

Comment: empty as in `object : {}`

Comment: An argument could be made for `null` instead of an empty object, but IMO an empty object would be best.  It leaves your main object the same so that it always has the same properties on it, and you can always rely on that without having to check if a property exists or not every time you use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume that `currentPlane` object has more properties like:

```
{
  "id": 3,
  "name": "Mary",
  "sex": "FEMALE",
  "currentPlane": {
    "airline": "american airlines",
    "flightNo": "A100354",
    "name": "null",
    "plane": "ATR725",
    "departureDate": "2020-04-26T07:00",
    "origin": "null",
    "arrivalDate": "2020-04-26T07:55",
    "destination": "null",
    "stops": 0
  }
}
```

so it is better to avoid using {} from server response. Now you should write a simple recursive iteration to remove null values

```
Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => {
  if (obj[key] === null) {
    delete obj[key];
  }
});
```

Finally, data refinements have been done and you can show data in template.